# How can I detect if IntelliJ IDEA or PyCharm is installed and get the path to the exe on Windows by using Python?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am looking for a piece of code Python code that would give me the path to IntelliJ IDEA or PyCharm exe if they are installed.

Usually, I would want to detect the same for Eclipse but it seems that Eclipse doesn't have an installer :(

Comment: Added as a bug to http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/PY-4921

Comment: Is it "Python code" or "code, Python code, ..." since you mentioned "exe" I'll assume windows =P, have you considered the registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation path is stored in the registry:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA\<build number>\(Default)`

(replace IntelliJ IDEA with PyCharm if you need the PyCharm installation path)

You can use the _winreg module to read the registry and retrieve the path.

Comment: So what do you expect to get from this StackOverflow question? The registry entries were designed to be used by our installer, and are perfectly adequate for its requirements. All of the difficulties you've mentioned can be overcome (and you can find out which version is the latest by checking the build.txt file in the installation directory). It's a simple matter of programming.

Comment: Note: there is a current bug in the installer, it does not always cleanup an old installation registry entries so you need to manually check if the path from registry is valid.